# Replace fragment with another in ViewPager ( after authorization)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have **3 (fragment1, fragment2, fragment3)** fragments in viewpager. The **fragment1** and the **fragment2** have a recyclerview inside. The **fragment3** is a simple login page.
What is the right way to replace **fragment3** with a new **fragment4** after authorization? (the **fragment4** has inside another recyclerview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option1:**

I would suggest setting total pages as 3 in view pager, then in your class which extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter,

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 1 or 2) {
        //Fragment 1 or 2
    } else if (position== 3) {
        if (isAuthorized) {
            //Fragment 4
        } else {
            //Fragment 3
        }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Keep Login and recycler UI part of Fragment 3 and toggle the UI as required.